# Зачем нужно неименованное пространство имен?

Tags: c++

какую пользу можно извлечь из подобной конструкции:

```
namespace{
    int i;
}
```

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf.aspx#Anchor_7): _и это полезно, когда вы хотите сделать объявления переменных невидимым для кода в других файлах (т.е. дать им внутреннее связывание) без создания именованного пространства имен. Весь код в одном файле можно увидеть идентификаторы в неназванной имен но идентификаторов, вместе с самим имен, не видны за пределами этого файла или, точнее за пределами ЕП._

Comment: @Grundy как я понял переменная **I** будет существовать только в текущем файле и будет доступна только для этого файла?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Польза та же, что и при использовании ключевого слова `static` — избегание проблем с *ODR (one definition rule)*. Если, к примеру, в заголовке у Вас будет `int i;`, тогда при подключении в 2 и более `.cpp` файла Вы получите ошибку линковки — один и тот же символ определён дважды. Если же Вы напишете `static int i;`, то `i` станет локальным для каждого объектного файла, в который `i` попадает — т.е. в каждом cpp будет свой `i`, в отличии от первого варианта, где `i` один на всю программу. То же самое происходит когда Вы пишите

```
namespace{
    int i;
}
```

`i` получает внутреннее связывание и, следовательно, проблемы с ODR не будет.

Comment: Связывание (linkage) бывает внешнее (external) и внутреннее (internal). Локального связывания нет.

Comment: @alexolut, ну я это и имел в виду

Comment: Я догадывался. Но это как "методы" вместо "функций-членов". Режет глаз и порождает новую базу терминов, что, имхо, не есть гуд.

Comment: Кстати, стоит отметить, что до C++11 анонимный namespace так же обладал уникальным именем, а вот функции и переменные там могли быть с внешним связыванием (другой вопрос: как к ним добраться): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces

Comment: @MonahTuk про уникальное имя namespace не оч.понял, т.к. в c++14 тоже есть про имя `unique` (см.7.3.1.1). По поводу как достучаться и т.д. задал [вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288838/external-linkage-for-name-inside-unnamed-namespace) на английском SO.

Comment: @alexolut, заметки(note) в стандарте можно смело пропускать, они не несут никакой «нагрузки», т.е. то, что в них написано не обязательно к исполнению

Comment: @alexolut, ну т.е. анонимный namespace не совсем анонимный, его имя просто генерируется компилятором, оно уникально.

Comment: @MonahTuk Можете указать какой конкретно пункт поменялся в Стандарте по этому поводу?

Comment: @alexolut По поводу анонимности - никакой. Т.е. уникальное имя так и генерируется. Только стало гарантироваться internal linkage. Смотреть по ссылке выше или C++11 (draft N3337) §3.5/4. В случае C++03 этот пункт выглядит совершенно иначе, а интерпретировать стандарт иногда то ещё удовольствие.

Answer (score 12):

Для каждого безымянного пространства имён компилятор генерирует уникальное имя, которое отличается от **любого** другого имени в программе.

```
namespace __Unique_Name__ {
   int i;
}
using namespace __Unique_Name__;
```

Особенно полезным свойством безымянных пространств является то, что их можно объявлять внутри других пространств имён, например, именованных.

Answer (score 8):

Не именованное пространство имен ограничивает видимость блока в пределах файла, где оно объявлено. Т.е из другого файла непосредственный доступ к переменной `i` ты уже получить не сможешь