# Что такое внутреннее и внешнее связывание?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Что такое внутреннее и внешнее связывание в языке C++ ?

Comment: Страуструп 4.2. http://www.cyberguru.ru/cpp/cpp-language-straustrup2-page52.html

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics там написано только про связывание, а я хотел бы понять что такое внутреннее и внешнее связывание и чем оно отличается друг от друга

Comment: А за что вопрос закрывать собрались?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Стандарт C++:

> When a name has external linkage , the entity it denotes can be
>   referred to by names from scopes of other translation units or from
>   other scopes of the same translation unit

и

> When a name has internal linkage , the entity it denotes can be
>   referred to by names from other scopes in the same translation unit.

По-русски это можно перевести как: внешнее связывание имеют те сущности, к которым можно обратиться в единице трансляции, отличной от той, где они определены. 
Например, имея в заголовке header.h:

```
extern int object;
```

в first.cpp

```
int object;
...
object = 5;
```

в second.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
...
object = 3;
```

Так вот, `int object`; в first.cpp имеет внешнее связывание, т.е. на него могут ссылаться другие единицы трансляции, что и делает second.cpp. Но чтобы second.cpp узнал, что такая переменная вообще существует, мы ему сказали через `extern int object;`. Таким образом получается, что несколько единиц трансляции обращаются к одному и тому же объекту в памяти. Это и есть *внешнее связывание*.

Внутренее связывание отличается от внешнего тем, что к сущности имеющей внутренее связывание нельзя обратиться из единицы трансляции, отличной от той, где она определена. 
Так, если взять тот же пример, но изменить first.cpp на

```
static int object;
```

или на

```
namespace
{
    int object;
}
```

и не трогать другой код то при линковке second.cpp мы получим ошибку линковщика, говорящую, что он не может найти `object`. Это происходит потому, что object имеет внутреннее связывание и, как я уже сказал, это значит, что другие единицы трансляции не могут видеть это имя.

---

Для лучшего понимания, можно воспользоваться следующей аналогией: у классов, в C++, есть несколько уровней доступа, в числе которых есть `private` и `public`. Компилятор проверяет, чтобы только внутренние части класса(опустим friend'ов и хаки) обращались к `private` членам, и любое обращение к таковым извне класса вызовет ошибку компиляции. С другой стороны, `public` члены доступны всем вокруг,— к ним может обращаться любая внешняя сущность.

Так вот, внутреннее и внешнее связывание ведут себя как `private` и `public` у классов, только ошибки тут выявляются на этапе линковки, а не компиляции. Другими словами, это ещё можно сказать так: сущности с внешним связыванием экспортируется за пределы единицы трансляции, тогда как с внутренним связыванием — нет, о них внешний мир вообще не знает.

Comment: >>  "то при линковке second.cpp мы получим ошибку линковщика". Маленькое замечание, при замене extern на static, мы получим две независимые переменные в first.cpp и в second.cpp (и возможно ошибку компилятора в first.cpp - если там подключен header.h)

Comment: @Mirdin, ну это скорее не замечание, а просто другой случай. Всех вариантов я рассмотреть в рамках одного ответа и не планировал :)

Comment: @ixSci спасибо за дополнение к ответу, хороший пример, все понятно

Comment: Для того, чтобы у человека, задавшего вопрос все окончательно сложилось в голове я бы также добавил, что "внутреннее и внешнее связывание" иногда также называют "внутренней и внешней компоновкой", а также сделал бы акцент на том, что спецификатор `static` (наличие либо отсутствие его) перед именем идентификатора как раз и задает способ связывания этого идентификатора (по-моему, сейчас ему придется додумывать этот момент), а также можно упомянуть тот факт, что существуют некоторые исключения, которые по умолчанию компонуются внутренним образом, например, константы (`const`) и `inline-функции`.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive не чего додумывать не надо я сегодня задал вопрос по этой же теме и вопросы дополняют друг друга http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490460/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD

Comment: Концепция "связывания" в языке С++ существено шире ее "приземленного" варианта в языке С. Связыванием в С++ обладают даже сущности, которые сами по себе не живут в памяти и о которых линкер не знает ничего. В частности: пространства имен, объявления класс-типов, объявления перечислений и шаблоны.